# Mac Terminal: Get list of Chinese fonts from a given folder

Tags: terminal, font

I have a personal folder with many fonts, and a small percentage are Chinese fonts. How can I list them with a terminal command in order to isolate them into another folder ?

I know `fc-list` but it will give me the list of Chinese fonts in the system folder:

```
fc-list :lang=zh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fc-scan -f "%{file}\t%{lang}\n" PATH | grep 'zh' | cut -f1 | sort | uniq
```

Replace PATH with the folder you want to scan. This spits out all filenames inside this directory which are at least of some language containing 'zh'.