# Get script/language for fonts via terminal

Tags: terminal, font, metadata

I would like to get the language support / script of any fonts I have in my computer with terminal command.
There is a way to see it through Font Book...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## `fc-scan`

You can use the command line tool [`fc-scan`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-fc-scan/) to list the properties of a font, including supported languages. The languages are reported under `lang:` as ISO two-letter country codes:

```
fc-scan /Library/Fonts/Arial\ Unicode.ttf
```

`fc-scan` is part of [`fontconfig`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fontconfig), which is available through the [brew project](https://brew.sh) using:

```
brew install fontconfig
```

See also [Mac Terminal: Get list of Chinese fonts from a given folder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366276)

Comment: Thank you, but I need solution that not involved libraries.

Comment: I am not aware of any built-in macOS tool that will show this information on the command line. `system_profiler SPFontsDataType` comes close but does not include the language field.